# Trying to download PDF's from website using HTML table in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I have webscraped the HTML table from https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do. I have placed this table into a pandas dataframe. I have also created another column for the dataframe called 'Match', whereby if an 'ASX Code' = 'SPL', it displays a 1. If you look at the website, you can see that the headlines are titles of PDF files which can be downloaded. I would like to download the file if the the 'Match' column = 1. Is this possible? Selenium?

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do')
for df in dfs:
    df.loc[df['ASX Code'] == 'SPL', 'Match'] = "1"
    df.loc[df['ASX Code'] != 'SPL', 'Match'] = "0"
    print(df)
```

**Dataframe:**

```
    ASX Code                 Date  Price sens.                                           Headline Match
0        SPL  15/04/2020  7:25 PM          NaN  SPL7013 shows significant activity against cor...     1
1        LSH  15/04/2020  7:19 PM          NaN  Change of Director's Interest Notice  2  pages...     0
2        PSQ  15/04/2020  7:14 PM          NaN  PSQ Implements Dividend Reinvestment Plan  25 ...     0
3        TGN  15/04/2020  7:11 PM          NaN  March Quarterly Report and Appendix 5B  24  pa...     0
4        GRR  15/04/2020  6:49 PM          NaN  Change of Director's Interest Notice  3  pages...     0
```

Comment: Why do you need pandas? if you want download pdf based on `ASX Code` you can do it only using selenium

Comment: I don't need it, I just use it for ease of use. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do couple of things.

You need to set `chrome option` for auto download pdf.

Induce `WebdriverWait`and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

Induce `WebdriverWait` and wait for windows and then switch to window then click on the lick `Agreed and proceed`

upon click on that pdf will auto down load to your default down load folder.

**code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/to/chromedriver",chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table//tr//td[text()='SPL']/following-sibling::td[3]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Agree and proceed']"))).click()
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Is there anyway I can change this line so that I can download files for multiple 'ASX Codes' WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table//tr//td[text()='SPL']/following-sibling::td[3]/a"))).click()

Comment: Yes you can.However for that you need to iterate list of ASX codes and logic would be a bit different.I would appreciate to post  a new question with new requirements.Thanks

Comment: I have posted a new question and would greatly appreciate if you can have a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61268278/12875715