# Find by xpath for multiple td tags

Tags: python, html, xpath

I would like to download PDF files from this website https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do if two conditions are met. The first condition is that the 'ASX Code' has to match one of the codes in a list. The second condition is that the 'Headline' has to match 'Change in substantial holding'. My current code only finds by xpath if the 'ASX Code' = 'SPL'.

**An example of what I am trying to achieve:**

```
data1 = ['SPL', 'WBC', 'AAA']
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table//tr//td[text()={data1}]/following-sibling::td[3]/a"))).click()
```

**My code:**

```
chromeOptions=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//table//tr//td[text()='SPL']/following-sibling::td[3]/a"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@value='Agree and proceed']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the data set with ASX code `data1 = ['SPL', 'WBC', 'AAA']` on web page at my location.However here is the example how to down load multiple ASX code in a sequence.

**Dataset**: `data1 = ['SW1', 'AME', 'BGA','PPT','AMP']`

Store `href` value of the in a list and then iterate the list and click on Agreed button to download the pdf.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chromeOptions=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/prevBusDayAnns.do")
data1 = ['SW1', 'AME', 'BGA','PPT','AMP']

pdfUrls=[]
for d in data1:
    try:
       pdfurl=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[text()='{}']/following-sibling::td[3]/a[contains(.,'{}')]".format(d,"Change in substantial holding")).get_attribute("href")
       pdfUrls.append(pdfurl)
    except:
        print("No ASX code found with Headline Change in substantial holding : " + d)


for pdfurl in pdfUrls:
    driver.get(pdfurl)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Agree and proceed']"))).click()
    time.sleep(10)  # pause to check download
    print("Downloaded pdf file")
```

Comment: Thanks. The for loop iterates over the first ASX Code in data1 five times which means there are five duplicate copies of the same PDF. For example, there would be five copies of SW1. The amount of times the for loop iterates over the first ASX code is equal to the amount of ASX codes in data1. For example, if there were ten codes, I would end up with ten copies of SW1. This only happens to the first ASX Code, everything else is fine. Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Ok.I will check and let you know.I’ll come back tomorrow.

Comment: Link to new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320949/for-loop-keeps-iterating-over-first-piece-of-data-in-list/61321098#61321098

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the XPath would be :

```
//table//tr[./td[1][.="SPL" or .="WBC" or .="AAA"] and .//a/text()[1][contains(.,"Change in substantial holding")]]//@href
```

Working example (16/04/2020) with another codes :

```
//table//tr[./td[1][.="AME" or .="SW1" or .="WEB"] and .//a/text()[1][contains(.,"Change in substantial holding")]]//@href
```

In Python :

```
values = ['SPL', 'WBC', 'AAA']
response.xpath('//table//tr[./td[1][.="' + values[0] + '"] and .//a/text()[1][contains(.,"Change in substantial holding")]]//@href').extract()
```